# reference variable in cpp modifying

Tags: c++

1)And i have seen many times that people uses this

```
 for(auto& row1: vect){
       for(auto& col1:row1){
           cout<<col1;
       }
  }
```

and there is a rule in c++ that if we declare reference variables then we can not change there reference once we declare them and then they can point to that memory location only but here every time `row` and `column` value are changing

2) My compiler is showing error in `printgraph` function in the for loop can anyone help me why auto is not working in this case and what exactly should happen that auto is not doing

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>

    using Graph = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

    void addedge(Graph &graph, const int u, const int v) {
        graph[u].push_back(v);
        graph[v].push_back(u);
    }
    void printgraph(const Graph &gph) {

        for (auto node : gph) {
            std::cout << node << " : ";
            for (auto x : gph[node]) {
                std::cout << x << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    int main() {
        Graph gph(8, std::vector<int>());
        addedge(gph, 2, 3);
        addedge(gph, 6, 7);
        addedge(gph, 1, 2);

        printgraph(gph);
    }
```

Sorry for asking two questions ,I know only you people can help me Thanks

Comment: One question per post please. *"Sorry for asking two questions"* If you know you're not supposed to do that, why not ask two separate questions to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, @FrançoisAndrieux comment's sums it well: for each entry on the loop, you get a new variable, so a new reference, they are not reused.

There is no definition to output a full vector:

```
std::cout << node << " : ";
```

`node` is a `vector<int>`, do:

```
for(size_t node=0; node < gph.size(); ++i)
```

instead, as you want to display the node id.

Comment: Yes indeed. There is no built-in operator<< for std::vector.

Comment: line 14 is wrong
```
for (auto x : gph[node]) {
     std::cout << x << " ";
}
```
node is ``std::vector<int>``